# How to get multiple adjacent data in a RDD with Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `RDD`, the `rdd`'s value is 0 or 1, and a limit is 4. When I map the `RDD`, if `rdd`'s value is 1 then the values from the current position to the (current position+limit) are all 1 else there are 0 0 .
example.

```
input :           1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
expected output : 1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1
```

This is what I have tried so far :

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
val limit = 4
val resultlimit = rdd.mapPartitions(parIter => {
  var result = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var resultIter = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  while (parIter.hasNext) {
    val iter = parIter.next()
    resultIter.append(iter)
  }
  var i = 0
  while (i < resultIter.length) {
    result.append(resultIter(i))
    if (resultIter(i) == 1) {
      var j = 1
      while (j + i < resultIter.length && j < limit) {
        result.append(1)
        j += 1
      }
      i += j
    } else {
      i += 1
    }
  }
  result.toIterator
})
resultlimit.foreach(println)
```

The result of resultlimit is `RDD:[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]`

My quick and dirty approach is to first create an Array but that is so ugly and inefficient.

Is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple. Import `RDDFunctions`

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
```

Define a limit:

```
val limit: Int = 4
```

Perpend `limit` - 1 zeros to the first partition:

```
val extended = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  case (0, iter) => Seq.fill(limit - 1)(0).toIterator ++ iter
  case (_, iter) => iter
}
```

Slide over the `RDD`:

```
val result = extended.sliding(limit).map {
  slice => if (slice.exists(_ != 0)) 1 else 0
}
```

Check the result:

```
val expected = Seq(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
require(expected == result.collect.toSeq)
```

On a side note, your current approach doesn't correct for partition boundaries, therefore result will vary depending on the source.

Comment: This is a very clean answer !

Answer (score 0):

Following is an improved approach to your requirement. Three `while` loops are reduced to one `for` loop and two `ArrayBuffer`s are reduced to one `ArrayBuffer`. So processing time and memory usage both are reduced.

```
val resultlimit= rdd.mapPartitions(parIter => {
  var result = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var limit = 0
  for (value <- parIter) {
    if (value == 1) limit = 4
    if (limit > 0) {
      result.append(1)
      limit -= 1
    }
    else {
      result.append(value)
    }
  }
  result.toIterator
})
```

**Edited**

Above solution is when you don't have a `partition` defined in the original `rdd`. But when a partition is defined as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), 4)
```

We need to `collect` the `rdds` as above solution will get executed on each `partitions`.

So the following solution should work

```
 var result = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var limit = 0
  for (value <- rdd.collect()) {
    if (value == 1) limit = 4
    if (limit > 0) {
      result.append(1)
      limit -= 1
    }
    else {
      result.append(value)
    }
  }
result.foreach(println)
```

Comment: can not use Array?This operation can only in one partition,it's Inefficient

Comment: @mentongwu Yes you are right. Let me see what I can do about it